# php using shell_cmd in program files directory

Tags: php, imagemagick, wkhtmltopdf

I've been struggling with this issue for a few hours now, and have absolutely no idea how to properly escape my syntax in order to run PHP's shell_cmd() function on a file in my Program Files directory.

Here is my current code:

```
$send_cmd="\C:\imagemagick\convert\" \"c:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\med_forms\\pdf\\tmppdf\\f-$time\\mf_pdf-$time-$file_num.html c:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\med_forms\\pdf\\tmppdf\\f-$time\\mf_pdf-$time-$file_num.pdf\"";

echo shell_exec($send_cmd);
```

I am trying to execute a command similar to:

```
 shell_cmd("C:\imagemagick\convert C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\med_forms\test.html C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\med_forms\test.pdf");
```

PHP has all of the proper folder permissions, and this command works without a problem when dealing with a folder structure with no spaces. How can I properly escape the spaces within my "Program Files" folder structure in order to execute the command?

I have tried using %20 for spaces, double back slashes (\) and now "\". Where am I going wrong? Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, i found the below suggestion or change to be implemented

1. Put the Imagemagick into environment path variable and check that it can be executed via command prompt also
2. Only write "convert" instead of giving path of imagemagick in script
3. Try to execute command "exec" instead of "shell_cmd" for windows [many times shell_cmd does not execute at windows server]

Also change the path of the html and pdf based on the WAMP server or project folder.

May this will help you....:)

Comment: I cannot change the path of the HTML file since this is where the web site is hosted. The Program Files directory listed IS my localhost. XAMPP/WAMP is not being used. This same exact script worked perfectly fine when the folder structure did not have spaces in it. The issue I am having lies in my "shell_cmd" syntax and being able to include spaces in the folder structure.